# selected="selected" is not working in IE11

Tags: jquery, internet-explorer

This is the old question but I am still not able to work it.Below is the code which i am having error.The options other than

```
<option selected="selected" value="-1">--Select--</option>
```

are got from ajax call and then added above option by

```
 var defaultOpt = "<option selected='selected' value='-1'>--Select--</option>";
$('#id').prepend(defaultOpt);
```

the problem is --Select-- not getting selected defaultly in IE.but isteat of prepend if i give append then its working fine.

```
<select name="id" tabindex="13" class="form-control" id="id">
<option selected="selected" value="-1">--Select--</option>
<option value="244">TCS</option>
<option value="236">CTS</option>
<option value="237">Wipro</option>
<option value="238">Polaris</option>
</select>
```

Comment: This should work.

Comment: Try `var defaultOpt = '<option value="-1">--Select--</option>';
$('#id').prepend(defaultOpt).val('-1');`

Comment: @PraveenKumar : yes i also think like that but append is working well but not for prepend in IE

Comment: @manoj Ah... Anyways, try Rory's suggestion? That should work!

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan : Your solutions is working but shall i know why my code is not working and also I already added more than 50 dropdowns in my application so i want to give it for each and every dropdown IDs.So is there any other option to make my code work

Comment: It's an IE oddity where adding a `selected` option is sometimes ignored if one already exists. You have to force the select to update the chosen value

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan oh my god then i want to repeat it for all my 50 dropdown IDs thats bad.Thank you Rory and praveen